# How to order my column names by month after I've used the function with() to pivot rows to columns in R?

Tags: r, date

I have this dataframe

```
df = structure(list(month = c("Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
                              "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
                              "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Aug", "Aug"), year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 
                                                                           2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
                                                                           2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), name = c("X20700254_SiteCode_9RB", 
                                                                                                                         "X20819833_SiteCode_7RB", "X20874286_SiteCode_5RB", "X20874298_SiteCode_.CB", 
                                                                                                                         "X20874301_SiteCode_.RB", "X20874311_SiteCode_4RB", "X20874315_SiteCode_.HB", 
                                                                                                                         "X20874322_SiteCode_3Fields_Brook_below_289_crossing.", "X20874323_SiteCode_6RB", 
                                                                                                                         "X20700254_SiteCode_9RB", "X20819833_SiteCode_7RB", "X20874286_SiteCode_5RB", 
                                                                                                                         "X20874298_SiteCode_.CB", "X20874301_SiteCode_.RB", "X20874311_SiteCode_4RB", 
                                                                                                                         "X20874315_SiteCode_.HB", "X20874322_SiteCode_3Fields_Brook_below_289_crossing.", 
                                                                                                                         "X20874323_SiteCode_6RB", "X20700254_SiteCode_9RB", "X20819833_SiteCode_7RB"
                                                                           ), avg = c(17.9671617647059, 17.96046875, 18.8039981617647, 12.7146985294118, 
                                                                                      19.8493308823529, 20.840299047619, 14.0127959558824, 17.7243290441176, 
                                                                                      20.8349797794118, 18.417934811828, 18.9261226478495, 18.6461377688172, 
                                                                                      16.4656639784946, 19.8924495967742, 20.5506465053763, 15.236438172043, 
                                                                                      17.2303807123656, 20.3705809811828, 17.2725913978495, 18.388158938172
                                                                           ), sd = c(1.01630124136236, 0.31920182877467, 1.44545541517925, 
                                                                                     0.233082255964961, 1.96762945427252, 2.22557010024103, 0.824501588774415, 
                                                                                     1.52965887463383, 2.21987506441605, 1.86382574377114, 2.00506644767057, 
                                                                                     2.32206032778809, 1.90349256072417, 2.86383652545279, 3.02180888784572, 
                                                                                     1.63882057453028, 2.20687928427123, 3.17513491088921, 1.76257380093557, 
                                                                                     1.5778580871338), max = c(20.234, 19.092, 22.046, 13.173, 24.351, 
                                                                                                               25.319, 15.473, 20.71, 25.61, 23.484, 26.488, 25.125, 22.525, 
                                                                                                               28.555, 29.953, 19.948, 23.1, 29.053, 23.581, 20.615), greater20 = c(0.0183823529411765, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0.242647058823529, 0, 0.431985294117647, 0.533333333333333, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0.0845588235294118, 0.566176470588235, 0.177083333333333, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0.269153225806452, 0.237903225806452, 0.0443548387096774, 0.428091397849462, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0.539650537634409, 0, 0.116935483870968, 0.512432795698925, 0.0443548387096774, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0782930107526882), greater23 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0698529411764706, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.253333333333333, 0, 0, 0.229779411764706, 0.00268817204301075, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0352822580645161, 0.0443548387096774, 0, 0.14885752688172, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.191868279569892, 0, 0.0030241935483871, 0.193212365591398, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.00235215053763441, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         month = c("Aug", "Jul", "Jun"), year = c(2020, 2020, 2020
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ), .rows = structure(list(19:20, 10:18, 1:9), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've pivoted this table using the following code

```
df_Greater20_ByMonth = with(df, 
                              tapply(greater20, list(name, month) , I)  )
```

and it has nearly given me what I wanted but the months were changed from characters to numeric, and they are now out of order. Does anyone know how to make them in proper order by month? Anytime I try to fix it before using the function `with()` the months just get changed back to numeric.

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a factor:

```
df$month <- factor(df$month, levels = unique(df$month))

df_Greater20_ByMonth = with(df, 
                            tapply(greater20, list(name, month) , I)  )
```

Comment: thank you. I was trying to change them into factors, but I must have been using the wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_wider` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(name, month, greater20) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = month, values_from = greater20)

#  name                                                    Jun    Jul     Aug
#  <chr>                                                 <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 X20700254_SiteCode_9RB                               0.0184 0.177   0.0444
#2 X20819833_SiteCode_7RB                               0      0.269   #0.0783
#3 X20874286_SiteCode_5RB                               0.243  0.238  NA     
#4 X20874298_SiteCode_.CB                               0      0.0444 NA     
#5 X20874301_SiteCode_.RB                               0.432  0.428  NA     
#6 X20874311_SiteCode_4RB                               0.533  0.540  NA     
#7 X20874315_SiteCode_.HB                               0      0      NA     
#8 X20874322_SiteCode_3Fields_Brook_below_289_crossing. 0.0846 0.117  NA     
#9 X20874323_SiteCode_6RB                               0.566  0.512  NA
```

Comment: Yeah this works great, but is it possible to change the column names from number to month abbreviated name?

Comment: As you can see from my output I don't get column names as numbers, they are month abbreviated names like Jun, Jul, Aug. I used the `dput` data provided in the post. Do you get some different output on the same data?